# Run XNA game with just XNA dll?

Tags: c#, windows, dll, xna, xna-4.0

I recently coded a XNA game with Visual Studio 2013. The question is in the title: can I run a XNA game with just the XNA dll included ? If yes, how? 
I use XNA 4.0

Comment: Why not just distribute the run-time with your game? That's the point of the runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is **NO**.

You need to include / check the following are installed on the target machine:

- The .NET Framework Redistributable
- XNA Framework Redistributable
- <del>DirectX Redistributable</del>

Please check [Distributing Your Finished Windows Game](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb464156.aspx) for a complete set of instructions on how to package and deploy your game. This includes the pre-requisites (.NET etc).

Comment: The XNA Redist includes everything it needs from DirectX/The C++ runtime and any Live for windows components. So you only need .Net and XNA

Comment: @TheZMan - Thank you for the edit / extra information.